# How to organize a GAE + GWT project with multiple modules

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I would like to know if someone can recommend a tutorial to organize my project, or to explain how to do it.

In my project I need these modules:

a) Core (entities classes + daos)
b) Backend (gwt module where the users can admin their app data, the
user must logu in)
c) Widgets (gwt module that loads an id in the url and displays a
widget that the users can put in their webpages, no need to be logued
to display the widget)
d) Restlet API 1 (an api that the users can use, i'm thinking to
develop this api with http://blog.noelios.com/2009/04/11/restlet-in-the-cloud-with-google-a...)
e) Restlet API 2 (another resltlet api for other purposes)

Modules b, c, d, e will load module a (Core).

And nothing else :)

Can someone give me an idea about how to organize the project?

Answer (score 1):

A general GWT project contains 3 packages client, server and shared, 
client package contains client side code, server contains backend code and entities, while shared package contains shared classes between client and server as data holders.

only Client, Shared folders are translated into JavaScript

So for organization,

- module a,b must be in server package.
- module c must be in client package.

for restlet apis, This needs to be developed on both server and client, The Client part sends rest requests and the server part replies to these requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a pretty nice blueprint for organizing your project here:

http://sonymathew.blogspot.com/2010/01/gwt-jee-blueprint.html

Also make sure you watch best practices video which has a cult status for gwt/gae architecture aficionados:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html